# Using Google shortenurl API to make short urls

Tags: c#, google-api, google-url-shortener

I am trying to use google shorten url to shorten a lot of urls for our project and keep getting an HTTPRequestException unhandled error. The first time I ran it it was asking to locate a .cs file which was not there so I am guessing it is due to that. I just used nugget installer to get this in visual studio. Any ideas?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Google.Apis.Urlshortener.v1;
using Google.Apis.Oauth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ShortenURL
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var originalURL = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Desert+Christian+Schools/@32.2367293,-110.8339121,16.75z/data=!4m7!1m4!3m3!1s0x86d66f1806d996d7:0xe8ac20e8cebb38b9!2s7525+E+Speedway+Blvd,+Tucson,+AZ+85710!3b1!3m1!1s0x86d66f1806d996d7:0x7b90764e4e6a25d8";
        string shortUrl = Shorten(originalURL);
        Console.WriteLine(shortUrl);
        Console.WriteLine("FINISHED");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    private const string key = "AIzaSyB3pfstkvAZzEVOy4dNHaKTuNmtDaG3XsI";
    public static string Shorten(string url)
    {
        UrlshortenerService service = new UrlshortenerService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            ApiKey = key,
            ApplicationName = "ShortenUrlAHLI"
        });
        var m = new Google.Apis.Urlshortener.v1.Data.Url();
        m.LongUrl = url;
        return service.Url.Insert(m).Execute().Id;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You should be more specific. At least full exception information.

Comment: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)

Comment: --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Execute() in C:\Apiary\v1.22\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\Support\GoogleApis\Apis\Requests\ClientServiceRequest.cs:line 101
   at ShortenURL.Program.Shorten(String url) in C:\Users\justinwendo\Desktop\test_VB_projects\ShortenURL\ShortenURL\Program.cs:line 37

Comment: An error occurred while sending the request.

   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Execute() in C:\Apiary\v1.22\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\Support\GoogleApis\Apis\Requests\ClientServiceRequest.cs:line 101
   at ShortenURL.Program.Shorten(String url) in C:\Users\justinwendo\Desktop\test_VB_projects\ShortenURL\ShortenURL\Program.cs:line 37

Comment: Sorry it would not let me post it all at one time because of too many characters.

Comment: OK, if you take a closer look on the exception message, you can see that the request can't pass throughout the proxy server which needs authentication.

Comment: I don't know why because I am passing the API key for authentication.

Comment: The api key for another purpose. You are connected to the Internet through a proxy server. You should solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //The code workable in my case :)  
    //VS2017        

    private static string shorten(string url)
    {
        UrlshortenerService service = new UrlshortenerService(
                new BaseClientService.Initializer() {
                ApiKey = "<google-api-key>",
                ApplicationName = "<google-app-id>", });
        var m = new Google.Apis.Urlshortener.v1.Data.Url();
        m.LongUrl = url;

        return service.Url.Insert(m).Execute().Id;
    }
```